# Travelling to Pakistan

Tags: international-travel, saudi-arabia, pakistan, ruh

My kid's British passport is expiring in April. We are travelling in February and coming back in March. They have valid NICOP. Are we ok to travel with two months validity? We have connecting flights in Riyadh.

Comment: Who is “they” ?

Comment: This time the they has to be the child. Modern use of English, not revealing the gender of the child.

Comment: @Willeke off-topic, but apparently singular use of "they" is not that modern: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55/42992

Comment: Are your kids dual British-Pakistani citizens? If so, which passport will they enter Pakistan using?

Comment: Are you connecting airside or landside in Riyadh?

Answer (score 3):

[Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/hk/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/visa-passport-information-results/?widgetheader=visa&nationality=gb&destination=pk) says the passport needs to be valid on arrival, without any other mention. However, since you don't say where you are transiting, this is not fool-proof.

Comment: Connecting flight via Riyadh.

Answer (score -2):

It's generally recommended to have at least 6 months validity on your passport for international travel. You might want to check with your airline and the countries you're visiting to be sure.

Comment: General recommendations are not useful for specific situations. We are looking for good answers. You could have posted it as a comment.